# In one end of table cell, concat all text from Cell A when Cell B is blank

Tags: worksheet-function, iwork-numbers

I've got a spreadsheet of potential expenses in Numbers.app.

```
Text String | $Price
```

In some rows, the `$Price` cell is empty.

I'd like to iterate over all the rows, and when `$Price` is empty, `CONCAT` the text from `Text String` into the cell.

---

Example:

```
Table | $100.00
Chair | 
Rug   | 
Plate | $50.00
---------------
Chair, Rug   <-- Concat'd text from Row 2, 3 because Cell B was Blank in each
```

Is this possible in Numbers.app? I thought maybe with `ISBLANK` and `CONCAT` but I'm struggling to get the syntax right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This scenario cannot be solved by worksheet functions. You'll need code for that.

Comment: Shoot. Thanks for saving me the wasted time of trying to figure it out.